# How do I trigger the popup dialog box automatically from iWebkit?

Tags: javascript, css, iphone

I'm creating a little iphone webapp for my school using the **[iWebkit](http://www.iwebkit.net)** (fancy css/javascript for making the interface for iphone / ipod touch web sites / webapps.

There is a feature called **Popup** which simulates a popup that you get in settings on your iPhone when you reset all settings (i.e. confirmation popup).

How can I make the popup appear **AUTOMATICALLY** when a HTML page is displayed - rather than having to click on the link per example of the user guide? (Page 22).  I've tried doing a onload in the body tag and even header tag but it doesn't work.

I don't want to use a javascript alert as it's not sexy.

This is what the code currently looks like based on Doug's suggestion below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<title>Popup Test</title>

<script src="javascript/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('load', function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    iWebkit.popup('popup1'); // Adjust this line to have the correct popup id
    }, 5000); // This is in milliseconds. Keep the number as low as possible so it still works
    }, false);
</script>
```

123






    
        Are you sure you want to do this?
            Stop Server
            Cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first the library (iWebkit) you are using is doing a "bad thing" by taking the entire `onload` event to itself instead of using the proper `addEventListener` function to attach itself to the onload function.

`onload` is the proper place to put it, but here is how you will need to call the popup on page load (add this after the `script src='/js/functions.js'` line)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
     iWebkit.popup('foodpopup'); // Adjust this line to have the correct popup id
  }, false);
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, it might be because both your function and their `onload` stuff is running at the same time. You can then try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
     window.setTimeout(function(){
        iWebkit.popup('foodpopup'); // Adjust this line to have the correct popup id
     }, 300); // This is in milliseconds. Keep the number as low as possible so it still works
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Doug.  I tried your suggestions, it didn't work.  I even tried increasing the timeout to 5000 - nope either.  :(

Comment: @Simon, sorry! I needed to be `window.addEventListener` not `document...`. I downloaded the latest copy of iWebkit and tested my first block of code (timeout not needed) and it worked once I changed it to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `onload` event?

Comment: I did try the onload event - I tried adding it in the body tag, header tag too.  Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Javascript alert? On iPhone, it is shown with a nice native UI style.

Comment: I did try the javascript alert - doesn't look sexy with the http://address at the top of that dialog box.  Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() {
            document.addEventListener('load', function(){  
    window.setTimeout(function(){  
    iWebkit.popup('popup1'); // Adjust this line to have the correct popup id  
    }, 100); // This is in milliseconds. Keep the number as low as possible so it still works  
    }, false);      
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this the same question from the iWebkit forum? if not, check out http://community.iwebkit.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=503 :)